# Error on using "mongoid-paperclip" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, image-upload

I use "mongoid-paperclip" gem for Image upload with mongodb in rails. The tutorial is: [Mongoid-paperclip](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip) . But I got following error
`undefined method "logger" for Mongoid::Config:Module`  
 How to remove this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip/blob/6dfdf7f9b4f44d80903a9ddbb6549f53ddb6116c/lib/mongoid_paperclip.rb 
and replace ur gem code and try it it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to find a resolution to this problem for a couple of hours, I got frustrated and tried a different approach and switched gems to carrierwave. It seems to work better with mongoid (at least I got it working immediately). So if you're not - for some reason unknown to me - stuck with paperclip, I suggest going with carrierwave, especially as Ryan Bates describes it as having more versatility.

- Here's the Railscast so you can decide if it's something you would like to use: [#253 CarrierWave File Uploads at RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

And here's the docs for carrierwave:

1. [Carrierwave Wiki at Github](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki)
2. [Carrierwave-Mongoid at Github](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid)

For me works like a charm with Rails 3 + Mongoid.

Comment: Can you provide any example code for how you configured it? It doesn't like my configuration somehow. Did you use mongoid 3.0?

Although I'm trying to use Sinatra which might be less well supported...